# convert pip requirements.txt to conda requirements

Tags: python, pip, conda

For `pip`, required libraries is stored in `requirements.txt`.

But at same workspace, I'm using `conda virtual environtment`.

Here is my `requirements.txt`

```
flask
werkzeug
Jinja2
watchdog
mongoengine
pyjwt
opencv-stubs
facenet-pytorch
Pillow
numpy
ultralytics
pylint
python-dotenv
```

What is the equivalent command for `pip install -r requirements.txt` with `conda`?

Comment: It's literally the [first search result on google](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-install-only-available-packages-using-conda-install-yes-file-requirementstxt-without-error/#understanding-the-conda-install-command)

Comment: @roganjosh how do I handle unavailable package not found, I ran it I got error `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channel` which is `opencv-stubs` and `facenet-pytorch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install libraries to a conda virtual environment using `pip`. Each environment has its own version of `pip`, and whenever you activate an environment, the `pip` command usually changes accordingly. For example, if I activate my base environment, this is the location of the pip application that  gets executed when I call `pip install x`:

```bash
Last login: Tue Sep  5 23:16:43 on ttys003
❯ conda activate base
❯ which pip
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

If I then change my environment to another called `"demo"`, here's what the `which pip` command returns instead:

```bash
❯ conda activate demo
❯ which pip
/opt/anaconda3/envs/demo/bin/pip
```

Notice that now it starts using `/opt/anaconda3/envs/demo/bin/pip` instead of `/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip`

**IMPORTANT:** The `which` that is used to locate the path of shell executables command does not exist for Windows. If you're using Windows, you can use `where` in the Command Prompt instead. The `where` shows you all the path(s) where an executable command is located on your system if it's in your `PATH`.

### Installing `requirements.txt` using `conda`

If instead, for some reason, you're trying to force the libraries from your `requirements.txt` to be installed using `conda`, try using the following commands:

#### For Mac-OS and Linux Systems

Simply run the following command:

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

#### For Windows Systems

1. Create a `install_conda.bat` batch script with the following contents:

   ```bash
   @echo off
   FOR /F %%i IN (requirements.txt) DO (
       conda install --yes %%i
   )
   ```
2. Run the batch script using command prompt:

   ```bash
   install_conda.bat
   ```

**IMPORTANT:** The above solutions might not install all packages since some might not be available in conda repositories.

### NOTES

If your conda environment is missing `pip`, you can install it using the command:

```
conda install pip
```